# Decode package and directory structure to URL from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` repo file

Tags: apt, repository, deb

I'm not an `apt` user, but I'm in a scenario, where I need to grab a `.deb` package off of a repo.

I'm not a user of a deb-based distro, so I can't easily install a `deb` repo for what I need it. This would also be impractical for other reasons.

Instead, I thought simply grabbing the package and then unpacking it, might be a simpler solution, but I'm having quite some trouble "deciphering" the repo entry in the `sources.list.d` directory:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.domain.de/ stable ubuntu
```

How do I turn this into some sort of URL that I can probe for things like a list of available packages or if I know the package name, just the URL to that?

In essence, it is in my case more practical too access a debian repo manually and grab that one package off of it, for unpacking and inspection, etc. rather than installing `apt`, and then install packages through that, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the entry is:

```
deb [arch=architecture] base-URL version repo-sections...
```

When you have a `sources.list.d` entry:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.domain.de/ stable ubuntu
```

that indicates:

- base-URL is `http://apt.domain.de/`
- version codename is `stable`
- architecture is `amd64`
- only one repository section `ubuntu` is listed.

It indicates that the list of relevant binary packages is located at `<base-URL>/dists/<version>/<repository-section>/binary-<arch>/Packages.(gz|xz)`, so:

```
http://apt.domain.de/dists/stable/ubuntu/binary-amd64/Packages.(gz|xz)
```

and that the actual packages are (most likely) at `<base-URL>/pool/<repository-section>`:

```
http://apt.domain.de/pool/ubuntu/
```

If the repository contains a large number of packages, it may have been split into a number of sub-directories under the second URL:

1. named with a single character, matching the initial character in the names of packages contained within
2. named as `libX` where `X` is a single character, containing library packages whose name without the `lib` prefix begins with the same character (i.e. `libX*`)

If there is a *really* large number of packages in the repository, there may be further sub-divisions.

So, if you were looking for package "foo", you would first download the file `http://apt.domain.de/dists/stable/ubuntu/binary-amd64/Packages.gz` or `http://apt.domain.de/dists/stable/ubuntu/binary-amd64/Packages.xz`, and read it to find out which version of that package is considered to be current in the `ubuntu` section of the `stable` version of that repository.

You would find something like this:

```
Package: foo
Source: foo (1.2.3-4)
Version: 1.2.3-4+b1
Installed-Size: 12345
Maintainer: The Developer Guy <email.address@domain.example>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libfoo (>= 1.2.3-4+b1)
...
Filename: pool/ubuntu/f/foo/foo_1.2.3-4+b1_amd64.deb
...
```

From this, you would know:

- that the relevant package is `foo-1.2.3-4+b1.deb`
- that it depends on package `libfoo`, version `1.2.3-4+b1` or greater
- and that the package can be found at:

  `http://apt.domain.de/pool/ubuntu/f/foo/foo_1.2.3-4+b1_amd64.deb`

You could then download the package to a temporary directory and start extracting it:

```
mkdir workdir
cd workdir
wget http://apt.domain.de/pool/ubuntu/f/foo/foo_1.2.3-4+b1_amd64.deb
ar x foo_1.2.3-4+b1_amd64.deb
```

This will give you three files: `control.tar.xz`, `data.tar.xz` and `debian-binary`. The last of those contains just a version number of the package format, and can usually be ignored.

The `data.tar.xz` contains the actual files that the package would install.

The `control.tar.xz` contains any pre/post install/remove scripts if the package requires them, and some metadata for the package manager.